# mailspring snap not launching

Tags: 18.04, snap, mate, email-client

I tried to install mailspring, because thunderbird icons don't work with my pc (the icons and text size isn't taken from system preferences)

But when when launching the snap, I get the error:

```
/snap/mailspring/244/bin/desktop-launch: line 185: /home/USERNAME

/snap/mailspring/common/.config/user-dirs.dirs: No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/USERNAME/snap/mailspring/common/.config/': Not a directory
/snap/mailspring/244/bin/desktop-launch: line 188: /home/USERNAME/snap/mailspring/common/.config/user-dirs.dirs.md5sum: No such file or directory
/snap/mailspring/244/bin/desktop-launch: line 188: /home/USERNAME/snap/mailspring/common/.config/user-dirs.locale.md5sum: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
^C
```

I then have to `^C` my way out.

Any ideas how to get this snap to run?

I'm on ubuntu, with the mate desktop installed later.